# Ant FTP action get not working

Tags: windows, unix, ant, ftp, solaris

We changed our shared Windows drive from filesvrA to filesvrB.

But, now our automated build processes are failing, because the FTP action fails when trying to get a file from a shared Windows directory to the local Solaris build box. It works fine on Linux, but not on Solaris.

When I say it fails, it doesn't throw any error message, it just says

```
0 files retrieved.
```

The FTP works fine with Filezilla, or with the Unix ftp command:

```
dv87adm@cmap02:/evaluate/xxx/xxxx$ ftp filesvrB
Connected to filesvrB.xxxxx.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (filesvrB:jayv): anonymous
331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Password:
230 User logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp> cd Evaluate/Releases/Sun/8.7/29
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful.
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
02-28-14  04:51PM                73728 Product Release Sheet.doc
02-28-14  05:01PM                73216 Release Installation Instructions.doc
03-03-14  02:38PM                  792 release.properties
226 Transfer complete.
554 bytes received in 0.00046 seconds (1179.52 Kbytes/s)
ftp> get release.properties
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
226 Transfer complete.
local: release.properties remote: release.properties
792 bytes received in 0.023 seconds (34.06 Kbytes/s)
```

But, the same thing with an ant script such as the one below:

```
<ftp action="get"
     server="${rollout.library.host}"
     remotedir="${rollout.library.install.path}"
     userid="${rollout.library.userid}"
     password="${rollout.library.password}"
     verbose="yes"
     binary="no">
  <fileset file="release.properties"/>
</ftp>
```

I get the following output:

```
 [echo] Getting evaluate.release.properties from /evaluate/Releases/Sun/8.7/29 on filesvr3
 [echo]
 [copy] Copying 1 file to /opt/xxx/xxxx/rollout
 [copy] Copying /opt/evaluate/xxx/xxxx/release.properties to /opt/evaluate/xxx/xxxx/release.properties.030514-165722
  [ftp] getting files
  [ftp] 0 files retrieved
[chmod] Applied chmod to 1 file and 0 directories.
```

It works when we change the file server to filesvrA.

I know I have to change some permissions on the new filesvrB, can anyone please point me in the right direction, as to what I have to check? What logs do I have to see?